# Efficient concatenation of Java LinkedList?

Tags: java, linked-list

The idea of LinkedList is, that each element has a reference to its successor (and predecessor in the case of doubled linked list), so concatenation of two LinkedLists happens that last element of the first list get reference to first element of second list [Detailed explanation here](http://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2014/02/concatenation-of-two-linked-lists.html), what is made in O(1) time.
Howewer they made it stupid in Java.
It has no method java.util.LinkedList.addFirst(LinkedList) or something.
if you look at the method java.util.LinkedList.addAll(Collection), it iterates over an array, what collection returns with c.toArray(), and then adds each element of this array. What is even twice stupid:

1) linked list is iterated in 0(n)
2) elements are added to linked list in 0(n) time.

Is there any possibility to extends the standart LinkedList so he would have good concatenation method? Because now, the simplest, but bad solution i see to make the copy- paste of LinkedList code and make some methods protected in order to extend that with implementation of right addALL

Comment: Such operation should also clear the other list. Otherwise you may try to change it (for example, adding new elements to the front) and this will break the concatenated list.

Comment: A node cannot appear in two lists at once so there is no simple way to pass nodes from one list to another. If you want a list which contains all the elements from two results, the best thing to do is add them to the same list in the first place.

Comment: @ Tagir Valeev good point, it will be practical to set list1 == list2 after this operation.
@ Peter Lawrey, and again : if list1 == list2 you would not have this problem

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `addAll` for that, because O(1) linked list concatenation is a ***destructive*** operation. In other words, you start with two non-empty lists, and end up with one big list and one empty list.

You are looking for two operations

```
void transferBeforeFirst(LinkedList<T> other);
void transferAfterLast(LinkedList<T> other);
```

They take `LinkedList<T> other` in whatever state it may be, and leave it empty upon return. This is rather counterintuitive, because generally the caller expects to find his data unchanged after calling a library method.

Of course, technically this could certainly be done. However, this goes against the grain of Java API design, which prefers to leave method parameters unchanged.

Comment: Can you link to the javadoc of those methods? I can't seem to find them.

Comment: @Ferrybig These methods are not there, I was trying to describe what they would look like if they were, and why it would be counterintuitive.

Comment: I would rather say, the operation list1.addAll(list2); must create list1 equal to list2. 
Arguments:
the operation must not destroy the "Java-like-pointers" to list1 and list2 and set they to null. It will be horrible confusing.
 If lists are ordered, the begin if list1 will be equal to begin of list2 , and then all nodes to the end are equal, thats why you can make list1 == list2

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is because special casing the adding of two linked lists together would destroy the sconfd list.

Notice that the `LinkedList.Node` class has both a `next` and a `prev` so it is indeed doubly-linked. To just join the chains together would make `list2.first.prev` point to `list1.last` which would then break `list2`.

```
public void addLast(LinkedList<? extends E> l) {
    // My list continues on into the new list.
    last.next = l.first;
    // Back-link too - THIS BREAKS l!!
    l.first.prev = last;
    // End of new list is now last.
    last = l.last;
}
```

Secondly notice that `LinkedList<? extends E>`. Remember that you can extend `LinkedList` so you may be adding two lists of a completely different class together - that would also require careful handling.

If you really want to achieve `O(1)` you could write an `IterableIterable` that would walk an `Itearble<Iterable<T>>` delivering each element from each `Iterable` in turn - kind of like a `flatMap` for `Iterables`.

```
class IterableIterable<T> implements Iterable<T> {

  private final Iterable<? extends Iterable<T>> i;

  public IterableIterable(Iterable<? extends Iterable<T>> i) {
    this.i = i;
  }

  @Override
  public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return new IIT();
  }

  private class IIT implements Iterator<T> {

    // Pull an iterator.
    final Iterator<? extends Iterable<T>> iit = i.iterator();
    // The current Iterator<T>
    Iterator<T> it = null;
    // The current T.
    T next = null;

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
      boolean finished = false;
      while (next == null && !finished) {
        if (it == null || !it.hasNext()) {
          if (iit.hasNext()) {
            it = iit.next().iterator();
          } else {
            // All over when we've exhausted the list of lists.
            finished = true;
          }
        }
        if (it != null && it.hasNext()) {
          // Get another from the current list.
          next = it.next();
        }
      }
      return next != null;
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
      T n = next;
      next = null;
      return n;
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: you have an overhead here because of additional hasNext() checks, and you would have crasy structure here like LinkedList<LinkedList>

Comment: @user1607242 - There is **one** additional `hasNext` check at the end of each `Iterable`. The structure is no crazier that a `List<List<T>>` or an `Object[][]` (which actually not `Iterable<Iterable>` but IMHO should be. My main point is that here I am concatenating `Iterables` in `O(1)` not `O(n)` as noted by question.

Comment: Actually I was wrong - ther eis an additional, unnecessary `hasNext` but that could be removed with a little effort.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do that, and the reason is that java has a strong object orientation and doesn't operate with data in a direct way such has C does, so if you have two linked lists and you want to make one out of two, you are forced to copy one of them entirely instead of only liking it at the end of the other one.

Answer (score -2):

That's why LinkedList has the addLast() method

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#addLast%28E%29

and it **does** have a addFirst() too

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#addFirst%28E%29

you can't do better than that, because Java has not the pointer concept.

you could try to implement your own native code for that, however.

Comment: That is not what OP is asking, though.

Comment: If the OP wants to concatenate a list into another, the OP must use addLast() or addFirst() to add one element at a time

Comment: The crucial point is that this would no longer be O(1), though.

Comment: "Java has not the pointer concept." It's not exactly right to say that the concept is not there. Although Java indeed does not have anything that is called a pointer, everything except primitives behaves very much like a pointer.

Comment: C has a pointer concept which is described in the language specification. Java does not.